# Find coordinates of fallen items in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

In my single player world, I landed my airship (pchan3's mod) to kill a few endermen, instead, I got killed by some mobs and lost a bunch of stuff. My spaceship is still out there (and probably my loot too). Is there a tool/mod with which I can process my world to find the location of the airship (and the dropped items) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another tip for the future for vanilla players who still use F3:

When you die, do not respawn.  Instead quit to the main menu.  Now open up a different world and hit F3.  Now quit that different world, and go back to your main world.  You'll still be dead, but now you'll be able to see your coordinates.  Hit F2 to take a screenshot and you can then respawn and run to the coordinates that you've screenshotted.

Note that the items you've dropped will not despawn until they're in a loaded chunk for five minutes (cumulatively).  So, if you're a LONG way away, take some time to gear up properly; you don't need to hurry until you're close enough that those chunks are loaded again.

Comment: One little addition - when you're at death-cam, the despawn-timer is still ticking, so try not to make a pause at that moment; check your coordinates and respawn ASAP. Moreover, timer doesn't reset when the chunk is unloaded, it's just paused.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore,

Answer (score 9):

**This is a tip for the future.** I've noticed, that you are OK with playing non-vanilla, so I recommend you to install the [Rei's Minimap](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/482147-100b181b19pre5dec12-reis-minimap-v29/). It's an awesome map mod, with all kinds of useful utilities, including the automatic death point logging (don't forget to turn it on) - it will put a cross on the place, where you died the last time.

However, these crosses accumulate pretty fast, so try to remember to delete them from the map, if you don't need them anymore. Otherwise, some day you will run a couple of thousands of blocks just for nothing.

Comment: yeah I stopped playing at 1.7 . Just bringing myself up to speed on the new stuff. airship lets me travel faster without feeling guilty about using fly mod :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tool [itemfinder](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2766743-itemfinder-just-died-and-cant-find-your-stuff-this-tool-will-show-you-where-it-is/). It lists all dropped items in the world, sorted by age and last chunk update.

[image]

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer.)

Comment: Link no longer works (if the mod has been discontinued I would appreciate if it were noted, if not just update the link)

Comment: This Project seems dead. You can find his Github easily, but unfortunately his app can't handle recent NBT files. I had the same problem as OP and MCEdit doesn't work well on Wine. (I'm on Linux.) So I ended up using Minutor ( http://seancode.com/minutor/ ) which is available on Windows/Mac/Debian (to my relief it's also available on the AUR).
It shows a Map and optionally entities like dropped items.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to look around your world using an [map editing tool](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors#Map_Editors) such as [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/) to find your airship and items.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here either show tips that can't be used if you are beyond the death screen or link to 3rd party apps that are either outdated or not available on all platforms.

This is why I recommend Minutor ([Official Website](http://seancode.com/minutor/)).

- It's available for Windows/MacOS/Debian [here](https://github.com/mrkite/minutor/releases).
- And also for Arch Linux [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/minutor-git).
- Others probably work if you compile it from [source](https://github.com/mrkite/minutor)

It shows you a map of your world where you can optionally display entities like dropped items (See `View`|`Entity Overlay`|`Items` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>). You'll find your inventory in no time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a small improvement to Scindix answer. Minutor make it hard to see where you exactly died.

Change Minutor::jumpToLocation in minutor.cpp to this (adding textbox with the location), so you get a popup which shows you the location of your last dead (only x,z coords, not the height).

```
void Minutor::jumpToLocation() {
  QAction *action = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());
  if (action) {
    Location loc = locations[action->data().toInt()];
    if ((loc.dimension == "minecraft:the_nether") && (m_ui.menu_Dimension[0].isEnabled())) {
      // dimMenu[0] defaults to Overworld
      loc.x *= 8;
      loc.z *= 8;
    }
    mapview->setLocation(loc.x, loc.z);
    //qDebug() << "Jumped to " << loc.x << " " << loc.z;

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(QString("Location: ") + QString::number(loc.x) + " " + QString::number(loc.z));
    msgBox.exec();

  }
}
```